# Sort by two query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

here I have a little problem with the sorting of member publications.

So I have two request and I would like to make a sorting function with `ORDER BY` I have tried to make an `ORDER BY (p.publication, pmembre.publication) ASC`

But it did not work.

That is my function:

```
function recup_publi_ami_membre()
{
    global $bdd;
    $query = $bdd->prepare("
    (   SELECT m.id_login, m.prenom, m.nom, m.affiche, m.id_admin, pmembre.publication
        FROM amis AS a
        INNER JOIN membre AS m
            ON IF(a.id_dest = :id, a.id_exp, a.id_dest) = m.id_login
        INNER JOIN publication_membre AS pmembre
            ON m.id_login = pmembre.id_auteur
        WHERE (a.id_exp = :id OR a.id_dest = :id)
            AND a.active = 1
    ) UNION (
        SELECT m.id_login, m.prenom, m.nom, m.affiche, m.id_admin, p.publication
        FROM membre AS m
        INNER JOIN publication AS p
            ON m.id_login = p.id_auteur
        WHERE m.id_login = :idget 
    )
    ");
    $query->execute(array('id' => $_GET['id'], 'idget' => $_GET['id']));
    return $query->fetchAll();
}
```

Comment: Pls be more specific as to what exactly you have tried and what was the error message you received or unexpected behaviour you encountered!

Comment: I have no error messages, the messages disappear When I try to do with the order by sorts.

Comment: The UNION will just create one publication field, so can you just do ORDER BY publication ASC?

Comment: Then I suggest you to add some proper error handling to your code!

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on [jkns.co's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35689073/sort-by-two-query#comment59056223_35689073):

Think of your query as

```
(
    SELECT
        m.id_login as field1,
        m.prenom as field2,
        m.nom as field3,
        m.affiche as field4,
        m.id_admin as field5,
        pmembre.publication as field6
    FROM ...
)
UNION
(
    SELECT
        m.id_login as field1,
        m.prenom as field2,
        m.nom as field3,
        m.affiche as field4,
        m.id_admin as field5,
        p.publication as field6
    FROM ...
)
```

The UNION creates a single result set for the two queries and the result set consists of records (all) having the fields1,...,field6. And you can operate on this result set almost like on a table (a derived table and you might want to "ask" [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) about the performance implications if you push too hard on that). So you *could* e.g. do something like

```
SELECT field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            m.id_login as field1,
            m.prenom as field2,
            m.nom as field3,
            m.affiche as field4,
            m.id_admin as field5,
            pmembre.publication as field6
        FROM ...
    )
    UNION
    (
        SELECT
            m.id_login as field1,
            m.prenom as field2,
            m.nom as field3,
            m.affiche as field4,
            m.id_admin as field5,
            p.publication as field6
        FROM ...
    )
ORDER BY field6 ASC
```

but
a) you don't have to wrap the union in another `SELECT ... FROM <derived table>`, the "shortcut" `( SELECT ... ) UNION ( SELECT ...) ORDER BY foo` will do.

b) you don't have to explicitly set the aliases to match the field names; MySQL will just use the names of the first UNION.

So,

```
( SELECT m.id_login, m.prenom, m.nom, m.affiche, m.id_admin, pmembre.publication
    FROM amis AS a
    ...
) UNION (
    SELECT m.id_login, m.prenom, m.nom, m.affiche, m.id_admin, p.publication
  FROM membre AS m
    ...
)
ORDER BY publication ASC
```

should do the trick.

edit: wait a minute.... those field names *do* match. Are you sure those should be two separate tables, instead of a single table with a flag field?

edit2: about not getting any error message: Since your code doesn't include "in-place" error handling you might want to [switch your pdo instance to `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php), e.g. when creating the instance:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly', array(
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY=>false,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));
```